# How to store uploaded file in mongoDB in Flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, file-upload, flask

In my [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) project I'm trying to get file uploads to work with MongoDB. Getting inspiration from [this upload tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/) I managed to upload a file and store it on the file system. Using [these mongoengine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html) I now wanted to store it in MongoDB as well.

My current document is defined as follows:

```
class UserDocument(mongoDb.Document):
    created = mongoDb.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, required=True)
    filename = mongoDb.StringField()
    _file = mongoDb.FileField()
```

and I uploaded and stored a file with the following view:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mytickets():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and isAllowedFile(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  # This works!
            userDoc = UserDocument()
            userDoc.filename = filename
            userDoc._file.put(file, content_type=file.content_type)
            userDoc.save()
        else:
            return 'We don\'t allow this file extension.'

    return render_template('upload.html')
```

The file gets created in the file system, so there IS a file. On the command line I verified there is one document in MongoDB, but it seems that the contents of _file are empty:

```
>>> UserDocument.objects.count()
1
>>> d = UserDocument.objects.first()
>>> d._file.read()
''
```

I figured it could be that you can't show image data on the command line, so I wondered how to show the document through Flask again. For this I made a simple Flask view to show one file:

```
@app.route('/show')
def showSomething():
    doc = UserDocument.objects.first()
    return doc._file.read()
```

This doesn't return anything though, either because the file never gets written to MongoDB, or because my showSomething is not correct, or both.

Would anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I tried reading the contents of the file and adding it to the document. This brings me a little further (see below) since read() now outputs some hex stuff. The thing is that I don't understand how reading it from a file and getting it from the Flask file upload is any different. Lastly; is there an easy way to display the output in the browser using Flask?

```
>>> from app.documents import UserDocument
>>> UserDocument.objects.count()
0
>>> f = open('/Users/kramer65/repos/tc/app/static/uploads/IMG_7599.JPG', 'r')  # I'm on MacOSX, so 'rb' doesn't exist
>>> userdoc = UserDocument()
>>> userdoc.filename = 'blabla.jpg'
>>> userdoc._file.put(f, content_type='image/jpeg')
>>> userdoc.save()
<UserDocument: UserDocument object>
>>> UserDocument.objects.count()
1
>>> d = UserDocument.objects.first()
>>> d._file.read()
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1%\xfeExif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x0f etc. etc.'
>>> d._file.read()
''  # Why oh why is it the second time suddenly an empty string?!
```

Comment: Did you try to open the file just saved with 'rb' mode and give it to the put method ?

Comment: @Dragu - Thanks for the tip. I tried your suggestion and added the result to my question above. This seems to do something, but the read() method still outputs an empty string. Any further ideas?

Comment: @Dragu - I edited my edit in my question, because I now get some hex output from `.read()`. The weird thing is that it doesn't output anything the second time I call `.read()` (see above). Any further ideas maybe? :S

Comment: Don't know why read() is working only onetime. I think you have to check how it's work on mongoengine's source code :)

Comment: Little late to the party, but the simple reason for this is because it's a IO object that remembers the index up to which you read the data. You can reset the internal counter using .seek(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time `read()` is returning empty string as the first one has already read and returned the entire content.